# save columns of matrix in vector variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab (R2021b) I am using some given function, which reads time-dependent values of several variables and returns them in a combined matrix together with a time vector. In the data matrix each column represents one vector of time-dependent values for one variable.

```
[data,time] = function_reading_data_of_several_values('filename');
```

For readability of the following code where the variables are further processed, I would like to store these columns in separate vector variables. I am doing it like that:

```
MomentX = data(1,:);
MomentY = data(2,:);
MomentZ = data(3,:);
ForceX  = data(4,:);
ForceY  = data(5,:);
ForceZ  = data(6,:);
```

That is working. But is there some simpler (or shorter) way of assigning the column of the matrix to individual vectors? I am asking because in real program I have more than the 6 columns as in the example. Code is getting quite long. I was thinking of something similar to the line below, but that does not work:

```
[MomentX,MomentY,MomentZ,ForceX,ForceY,ForceZ] = data; %does not work
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks for help!

Update:

---

Thanks to the hint here in the group to use tables, a solution could be like this:

```
...
[data,time] = function_reading_data_of_several_values('filename'); 
% data in matrix. Each column representing a stime dependent variable

varNames = {'MomentX', 'MomentX',...}; % Names of columns 
T=array2table(data','VariableNames',varNames); % Transform to Table 
Stress = T.MomentX/W + T.ForceY/A   %accesing table columns
...
```

This seems to work fine and readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: In industrial solutions like dSpace, it is very common to do it in struct arrays:

```
mydata.X(1).time = [0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04];
mydata.Y(1).name = 'MomentX';
mydata.Y(1).data = [1 2 3 4];
mydata.Y(2).name = 'MomentY';
mydata.Y(2).data = [2 3 4 5];
```

Solution 2: It is also very common to create tables
See: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints.  About Solution 1: Yes, struct like format would be nice. But since I am using a function of an existing toolchain, I have to work with return value format as it is.

Comment: About Solution 2:  that might help working with table. I could transfer the matrix to a table and work with that like so:     varNames = {'MomentX', 'MomentX',...};
                T=array2table(data','VariableNames',varNames);
                Stress = T.MomentX/W + T.ForceY/A %subsequent calculations

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, it is probably better to use a table instead of separate variables may not be a good idea. But if you want to, it can be done this way:

```
A = magic(6): % example 6-column matrix
A_cell = num2cell(A, 1); % separate columns in cells
[MomentX, MomentY, MomentZ, ForceX, ForceY, ForceZ] = A_cell{:};
```

This is almost the same as your

> `[MomentX,MomentY,MomentZ,ForceX,ForceY,ForceZ] = data; %does not work`

except that the right-hand side needs to be a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), which in this case is obtained from a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).